# Configure a threshold used on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a program running on AWS Lambda like the following.

```
threshold = 10
def alerting(x, y):
    ans = x + y
    return True if ans > threshold else False
```

There is one problem that I need to change the program and deploy if I want to use another number as a threshold. I'd like to change the threshold dynamically. What kinda AWS solutions can be used for that? I thought I should put a config file on S3 and then the program on Lambda tries to read it to use as a parameter when it is invoked for example.

Is there any better solution with AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple case you can either use `Environment Variables` or `Systems Manager Parameter Store` and attach to your Lambda function's execution role a policy to access this parameter.

Comment: Correct answer. One addition: if the Lambda is used with an API Gateway there is also the option to configure the threshold using stage variables.